# CKEditor 4 ignores uploadUrl response and still uses blob URL with a successful and error message at the same time

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am configuring the CKEditor 4 with:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
            height: 300,
            uploadUrl: '/upload'
        });
```

The /upload returns:

```
{
    "uploaded": 0,
    "error": {
        "message": "The file is far too big!"
    }
```

But in the interface, I get successful and error at the same time.
[image]

I can see that in the source I get:

```
<figure class="easyimage easyimage-full"><img alt="" src="blob:http://192.168.0.101:5900/7137501d-da6a-41bc-956a-d3d6f2cf1d39" width="601" />
<figcaption></figcaption>
</figure>
```

I guess it is a configuration problem, but after reading the documentation I cannot see what it's wrong.